# delete files by iterating an array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two arrays which has file numbers and I need to read those two arrays and delete those files. I need to read `pri` array and delete files inside `/primary` directory. Similarly I need to read `snd` array and delete files inside `/secondary` directory. These two directories have lot of other files and other subdirectories as well so I need to be very careful. I just need to delete files which are mentioned in those two arrays only.

All file names are like this:

```
abc_monthly_5_log.data
abc_monthly_25_log.data
abc_monthly_78_log.data
```

Below is my script and I can iterate them and delete those files one by one. Is there any other better way by which I can do that?

```
# it will lot of file numbers not just four or five files
pri=(0 5 7 100)
snd=(9 8 187 90 156)

# iterate pri array and delete files inside
for pm in "${pri[@]}"; do
    rm /primary/abc_monthly_"$pm"_log.data
done

# iterate snd array and delete files inside
for sm in "${snd[@]}"; do
    rm /secondary/abc_monthly_"$sm"_log.data
done
```

Comment: Looks like a reasonable solution. Your code is clean and immediately understandable. Unless you have serious performance problems I don't see why you would want to change it.

Answer (score 2):

A "better" way, which is "better" in that it executes `rm` less often, would be to use `xargs`:

```
{
    for pm in "${pri[@]}"; do
        printf '/primary/abc_monthly_%s_log.data\n' "$pm"
    done

    for sm in "${snd[@]}"; do
        printf '/secondary/abc_monthly_%s_log.data\n' "$sm"
    done
} | xargs rm
```

This would use the loops just as a mean for generating pathnames. These pathnames are then passed to `xargs rm` which would execute `rm` on as many of them as possible at once. With the example arrays that you have provided, it would probably just run `rm` *once*.

The way I have written it above assumes that none of the path components contain literal newlines or whitespace (which they don't do in this example).